# Set Wallpaper using URL

Tags: android, android-glide

I'm trying to set wallpaper, using wallpaperManager and image from the internet, but because of the fact that it warks only with Int, my app doe not work.

I suppose that I should use

```
int setBitmap (Bitmap fullImage, 
            Rect visibleCropHint, 
            boolean allowBackup, 
            int which)
```

but I do not know how.

My code

```
String imgPut = "http://geekart.club/GeekArt/SW/Dark_Side/Darth_Sidious_from_TFU.jpg";

            WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager
                    = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getContext());
            try {
                myWallpaperManager.setResource(imgPut);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Comment: `setResource()` is for resources. You do not have a resource. Download the image, then use `setStream()` or `setBitmap()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) to load the images from url:

```
Picasso.from(mContext).load(url).into(imageView);
```

Comment: but how to set image into  ->  myWallpaperManager.setResource(IMAGE)? How to find ID of that image?

Comment: @PavelCoder There will be no resource id, you will use the Picasso to get the image drawable, and use the ImageView itself, not the resId